# Load Image in writableBitmap and Convert image pixel color

Tags: image, windows-phone-7, colors, pixel

How to change Image pixel color and update image in wp7 using c#

Here, I have already loaded one jpg image in img1 source. I want to load that image to writableBitmap and convert the pixel color. I have tried, but i got an empty image.

```
WriteableBitmap writeableBmp = new WriteableBitmap(512, 512);
writeableBmp.Render(img1, null);

for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
{
    writeableBmp.Pixels.SetValue(21, i);
}

img1.Source = writeableBmp;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the Writeable Bitmap from the BitmapImage converted using JPG image.

And then change the value and assigning to Image control is as follows .

Please check is this solve your problem .

```
BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage(new Uri("JpegImageUri", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

WriteableBitmap wbmp = new WriteableBitmap(bmp);

for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
{
    wbmp.Pixels.SetValue(21, i);
}

Image image = new Image();
image.Source = wbmp;
```